# Anonymous function in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I try to run this code in matlab. I want to add a anonymous function. This function itself has a variable changing for each iteration. I could not succeed. Could anybody provide me a solution? Thanks in advance.

```
y=[1 2];
a=@(x) 3*x+y.^2;


for n=1:2
a=@(x) a(x) + 3*x+y(n)^2; 
end

a(1)
```

Comment: what you want to do exactly?

Comment: I want to add an anonymous function recursively. But a component of function changes for every iteration. in this case 'y' is changing.

Comment: In this case, your answer must be y=[12 21]?

Comment: answer is 11. but Matlab shows the following answer.              ans =

    15    18

Comment: @Janu: you are making the code hard to read. Can you walk us through how you got the result of `11`, by showing the equation and values substituted at each step? You seem to be using `y` as a 2-element array in your first definition of `a`, but then you start using it as a scalar `y(n)` in the recursive definition, so you are bound to get a 1x2 array as a result...

Comment: It would be better if you describe what equation you are trying to implement, maybe by showing the definition in mathematical notation?

Comment: @ Amro in the first iteration a=3x+y^2; here y=1, x=1 so a=3+1=4. in the second iteration x=1,  y=2 so a=4+3*1+2^2 = 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, try the following instead:

```
function out = f(x)
    y = [1 2];

    out = 0;
    for n=1:numel(y)
        out = out + 3*x + y(n)^2;
    end
end
```

with:

```
>> f(1)
ans =
    11
```

no need for recursion, and much easier to read

Comment: you can vectorize it simply as: `y = [1 2]; f = @(x) sum(3*x + y.^2)`